# set existing foreign key column to nullable in alter table migration

Tags: php, laravel

I first created a migration like this:

```
Schema::create('table1',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->integer("user_id")->unsigned();
        $table->foreign("user_id)->references("id")->on("users");
});
```

Then i wanted to add nullable property to user_id column , i wrote this migration:

```
Schema::table('f_subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->change();
        $table->foreign('original_law_id')->references('id')->on('f_original_law');
    });
```

But i got this error:

```
Cannot change column 'user_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'table1_user_id_foreign'
```

Answer (score 10):

1- Delete your foreign key

```
$table->dropForeign('table1_user_id_foreign');
```

2- Change user_id column definition:

```
//If user_id is not unsigned remove unsigned function
$table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->change();
```

3- Create index

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Complete migration:

```
Schema::table('table1',function(Blueprint $table){
    //Or disable foreign check with: 
    //Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    $table->dropForeign('table1_user_id_foreign');
    $table->integer('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->change();
    //Remove the following line if disable foreign key
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

Comment: I had to pass an array to $table->dropForeign like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48188241/1891952 answer below. I assume this is due to a later version of Laravel.

Answer (score 6):

**1.** You need to drop the constraint first:

```
$table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
```

**2.** Or you could temporarily disable FK constraints:

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

And then enable constraints:

```
Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 2):

Always use these codes in migrations:

```
 public function down()
    {

        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::dropIfExists('table');
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I can not drop table, because it has some important data

Answer (score 0):

run this command in your project root folder:

```
php artisan make:migration change_user_id_to_nullable_in_table1_table --table=table1
```

and in new migration file write this code:

```
Schema::table('table1', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->change();
});
```

then run this command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

if that not work check your code, maybe you filled your foreign key field by zero or other wrong value instead of parent table id.